# Cleaner way to return an object from within a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am currently doing this to return a user object from an array

```
const userIndex = users.findIndex((user) => { return user.id === source.userId; });
const user = users[userIndex];
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

This is a reactjs app so I have the option to use any fancy library if necessary.  I have lodash in my packages in case that would help.

Comment: Why not just use `.find()` instead of `.findIndex()`?

Comment: `const user = users.find(({id}) => id === source.userId)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaner approach using the function **[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**:

```
const user = users.find(({id}) => id === source.userId);
```

*Example*

```js
const users = [{
  id: 2,
  name: "Ele"
}];

const source = {
  userId: 2
};

const user = users.find(({id}) => id === source.userId);

console.log(user);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```